# How do I get 'Main Menu' back?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, menu

In 11.04 and previous editions of Ubuntu, I used the 'Main Menu' tool (under 'System/Preferences') to change individual icons that I did not like in the icon theme I use (Faenza, and mainly the Firefox icon is what I like to change).  I now don't have the 'Main Menu' and I can't find it in Synaptic.

Do you know how I can add this back or install it?  Is there a new way to do this with 11.10.  To me, it seems Ubuntu has gotten harder to set up the way I like with this edition.  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Main Menu* is also known as *alacarte*

Funnily enough in Software Center it is also known as *Main Menu*!

[image]

Once installed -from dash...

[image]